# Read and write to json via html with out php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am able to run this successfully. I would love to accomplish the same thing with out the use of php. Main goal is to change the value of sel from the json file.  Below is my php code and json code. the user.php changes the vaule of sel from the json file when a button is hit.

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('sel.json');  //read contents from json file
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonString, true);             //convert string into json array using this function
if(isset($_POST['button1']))      //if button is pressed?
{
    $jsondata[0]['sel'] = 1;      //initialise data to 1
}
if(isset($_POST['button2']))      //if button is pressed?
{
    $jsondata[0]['sel'] = 2;      //initialise data to 2
}
if(isset($_POST['button4']))      //if button is pressed?
{
    $jsondata[0]['sel'] = 4;      //initialise data to 4
}
if(isset($_POST['button6']))      //if button is pressed?
{
    $jsondata[0]['sel'] = 6;      //initialise data to 6
}

$newJsonString = json_encode($jsondata);     //encode data back 
file_put_contents('sel.json', $newJsonString);      //write into file
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>json testing</p>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">     
    <button name="button1" onclick="placeorder()"> sel1:place order</button>
    <button name="button2" onclick="cancleorder()">sel2:cancle order</button>
    <button name="button4" onclick="unlockenotdone()">sel4:unlock UV box(notdone)</button>
    <button name="button6" onclick="unlockedone()">sel6:unlock UV box(done)</button>
</form>
<p id="ui"></p>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("ui");
    function placeorder() {
        
        console.log(1);
        x.innerHTML = "Your Order has been Placed";
        clear();
    }
    function cancleorder(){
        var usrResponse=confirm('are you sure you want to cancle the order?');
        if(usrResponse==true){
            cancleconfirm();//call function ChangState2()
            }
        }
    function cancleconfirm() {
        console.log(2);
        x.innerHTML = "Your Order has been canceled";
        clear();//call function clear()
    }
    function unlockenotdone(){
    var usrResponse=confirm('The sterilization is not done. Do you still want to unlock the book?');
        if(usrResponse==true){
            console.log(4);
            openconfirm();
        }
    }
    function unlockedone()
    {
        console.log(6);
        openconfirm();
    }
    function openconfirm() {
        x.innerHTML = "The UV book is now unlocked";
        clear();//call function clear()
    }
    function clear()
    {
        setTimeout( function(){x.innerHTML="";}, 5000);
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the sel.json [{"sel":1}]

Answer (score 1):

Simply javascript can never do this, you must have to use of javaScript as well as php for this scenario..

You need to use XHR

step 1 -> handle file saving process as backend using php code.
step 2 -> make a method for button to hit a xhr code to excecute set1 file code

here we go

**step 1**

creating file with name `savingJson.php`

```
/* This is savingJson.php file */
/* here file saving code to handle */

  $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

  // define path for file
  $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sel.json'; 

  // Write the contents back to the file
  file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

**step 2**

calling XHR method on button click to run `savingJson.php` using javaScript

```
var jsonData = '[{"sel":1}]'

// calling method on button click
var button = document.getElementbyId("btn_id")
button.onclick = function(){
    saveJsonToFile(jsonData)
}

function saveJsonToFile(jsonData) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'savingJson.php'        /*path to savingJson.php file*/
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);      /* must be use POST for large data*/
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(jsonData);
}
```

Hope so this will help you,
Happy Coding!